# SSH tunnel with terminal

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm a beginner at ssh so be kind with my limited knowedge ;)

What I want to do is as follow:

SSH to a PC and then from this PC SSH to another one, see picture below:

[SSH Tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spJri.jpg)

Here are the commands I run when I do it manually:

```
ssh user@155.254.0.1
```

After this command I will be prompt to enter the password.

From here I ssh again to the next "PC" with the following command:

```
ssh root@190.22.0.1 -y
```

and then I get prompt to enter the password.

I tried to use a python script to do it automatically by I was not able to come to the next seconds step.

Here is how the python code looks like:

```
import subprocess

cmd_1 = ["ls"]

cmd_3 = ['ls', '-l']

def send_top_cmd():
    cmd_2 = ['top', "-b", "-n", "5"]
    com2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd_2, stdout=out)
    com2.wait()

def send_ssh_pc_1():
    cmd = ["sshpass", "-p", "'user'", "ssh", "swupdate@155.254.0.1"]
    ssh_sga = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out)
    ssh_sga.wait()

def send_ssh_pc_2():
    cmd = ["sshpass", "-p", "'root'", "ssh", "root@190.22.0.1"]
    ssh_hpa = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out)
    ssh_hpa.wait()

def send_exit():
    cmd = ["exit"]
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out)
    cmd = ["exit"]
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out)
    print("done")

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    send_ssh_pc_1() # ssh PC 1
    send_ssh_pc_2() # ssh PC 2
    send_top_cmd()  # Send a simply command
    send_exit()
```

The script fails at the "send_ssh_pc_2()" since I dont have sshpass installed and there's no possibility to install it there :(

Is there a easier way to do it automatically?

Comment: Use RSA keys instead of password authentication. Makes your life much easier.

Comment: By the way, what are you trying to do? SSH tunneling would be your friend here.

Comment: I'm just trying to check the status of the last PC... testing out/playing around.

Comment: I will check how to add the RSA keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much easier to write as an answer instead of comment.

First, enable RSA authentication for both of your SSH boxes. Then you don't need to worry about passing password. https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication

Then open SSH tunnel from your computer with following command:

```
ssh -L 2222:190.22.0.1:22 user@155.254.0.1
```

That will enable tunnel from your local computer port 2222 to host in address 190.22.0.1 port 22. So next you can open SSH connection to the target computer like this.

```
ssh -p 2222 root@localhost
```

If your RSA private key is authorized to both user@155.254.0.1 and root@190.22.0.1 no passwords should be asked and you have SSH connection to 192.22.0.1 from your workstation.

Of course you can tunnel any TCP traffic, not just SSH.

*** ADDED ***

Here is example of content of authorized_keys -file (some content removed).

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA3fauf5H3kN92Gxx8xerCF***********************************************************************************************************************PPIrUMdf1948pqLspom8SIyeqJeKX8wVqcJch35O0Q4UVlbw== user@host
ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nzaasdfrgaa4634w4gfdewrtfauf5H3kN92Gxx8xerCF***********************************************************************************************************************PPIrUMdf1948pqLspossdfgqrbbsrdtwetdsfgsfdgsd== admin@anotherhost
```

Comment: How do I enable RSA authentication for both of your SSH boxes?  I've run ssh-keygen but what is the next step (Sorry my noobiness )

Comment: In each user you want to authenticate with RSA you need to add your public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file

Comment: and the same directory there is file named config. you may need to enable RSA auth there.

Comment: I just have 3 files inside /home/user/.ssh: id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and known_hosts

Comment: If you don't have authorized_keys, just create it. Each key you use on own line.

Comment: Do you have a example on how the file should look like? and I dont have the config file... should I create it as well?

Comment: Added it to answer.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server <- this looks good step-by-step guide

Comment: Oh, and that tunneling isn't depending on RSA auth. It just makes your life easier. But you can test those SSH commands from your terminal and write password when asked.